# Удалить все записи из Set в Aerospike

Tags: java, aerospike

Я использую вот эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java) на java для работы с Aerospike.
Для удаления всего сета я сначала скачиваю все из него, а потом делаю удаление каждой записи.

Но размер данных настолько вырос, что приложение не способно скачать все что бы удалить в последующем.

Можно ли с помощью нее очистить весь сет? Или удалить его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, вам подойдет метод [`com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient#truncate`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/client/src/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.java#L584-L601)

```
client.truncate(infoPolicy, "my-namespace", "some-set", null);
```

Это будет эквивалентно команде [`truncate`](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/#truncate) info-протокола:

```
asinfo -h "truncate:namespace=my-namespace;set=some-set"
```